# how to redirect with js and alert if turn in previous page?

Tags: javascript, php, function, methods, href

i want to redirect to a php page for example `example.php` and  make possible not to turn back to the first page,if try to turn i must alert the user.i dont want do delete the page from hisotry.
Any of that insrtuction:

```
    window.open('example.php','_self') or
    location.href:example.php or
    header("location: example.php) or
or location.replace('example.php;)
```

cant do what i want.
is there any javascript method or php function to make that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: header('Location: http://localhost/Prac/updateinsamepage.php'); 

personally i used like this and it work for me

Comment: i must to redirect

Comment: yeah it is used for redirect to another page in your case like
header('Location: example.php ');

Comment: What do you need to do? Prevent going back from `example.php`?

Comment: or try to replace it 
location.replace( 'example.php' );

Comment: Is there any php function for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript you can use `location.replace()` to assign a new url - it forgets the previous location ( removes from history )

```
location.replace( 'example.php' );
```

For reference, try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)